# TF.EXE command excluding executable (*.DLL) files

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tf-cli

I'm using the `TF.EXE` utility to automatically move some build output into TFS as part of our automated build process.

Here's the command line:

```
tf.exe add C:\Output\*.* /recursive /noprompt
tf.exe checkin C:\Output\*.* /recursive /noprompt
```

It all works great, apart from the wrinkle that one of the output files has the `.dll` extension. Initially this file gets picked up as you'd expect, and then towards the end it prints this helpful message:

```
Items matching the following exclusions were ignored: *.dll
```

Comment: You shouldn't be putting binaries in source control. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution was to include the `/noignore` switch on the `add` command, like so:

```
tf.exe add C:\Output\*.* /recursive /noignore /noprompt
```